# React get json data from http

Tags: json, reactjs

i am newbie en react technologie.

how can i get the json data from http request ?

as you can see on [image]

i can get the value of `console.log(dataExt);` from inside this function,
but i can not get the value of `console.log(dataExt);` from outside this function.

i miss something ?

i did use `return dataExt;` why i get nothing ?

i have modified my function:

```
async function getDataExt()
{   
  try {
    let response = await fetch('https://xxxx');
    let dataExt = await response.json();
    console.log(dataExt);
    return dataExt;
   } catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

but still i can not get the value [image]

Comment: can you make your function async and add await before calling it?

Comment: Please consider adding code via Snippet or Code Sample instead of picture. Thanks

Comment: `return dataExt` returns a promise, it's not synchronous

Answer (score 1):

The `fetch` call is asynchronous and returns a `Promise`, that's why you need to call `then` to get the result. As it stands, line 62 will not wait for the `fetch` in `getDataExt()` to complete before running the `console.log`. You need to treat `getDataExt` as an async function and either do `async`/`await` or `.then()`.

Comment: i didasync function getDataExt()
{   
  try {
    let response = await fetch('https://xxxx');
    let dataExt = await response.json();
    console.log(dataExt);
    return dataExt;
   } catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the asynchrony, that is, the "`return`" is executed when it obtains the value in the request it makes, and that takes time. Let's say it takes 1 second for the data to return, but 0.1 for the variable to print, that means it prints first and then assigns the value. Now, a possible solution would be to **create** a "`state`" to save that data or how the partner said, **create** the function `getDataExt` as an `asynchronous function`.